# Hypothesis test and probability distribution

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, self-study, normal-distribution, multivariate-analysis

> Let $X\sim N_p(\mu,\Sigma)$. Suppose that we desire to test $H_0:\mu=\mu_0$ vs $H_1:\mu\neq \mu_0$
>   with $\Sigma$ known and unknown where
>   $\mu_0=(\mu_{01},\dots,\mu_{0p})$. Verify that under $H_0$
>   $$Q=n(\bar{X}-\mu_0)'\Sigma^{-1}(\bar{X}-\mu_0)\sim \chi_p^2$$
>   $$F=\frac{n-p}{(n-1)p}T\sim F_{(p,n-p)}$$ where
>   $T=n(\bar{X}-\mu_0)'(S^2)^{-1}(\bar{X}-\mu_0)$ and under $H_1$ $$Q\sim
>  \chi_{(p,\delta)}^2 \quad F\sim F(n,n-p,\delta)$$ with non-centrality
>   parameter $\delta=n(\mu-\mu_0)'\Sigma^{-1}(\mu-\mu_0)$

I know that $\bar{X}\sim N_p(\mu,\frac{1}{n}\Sigma)$then let $Y=\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}-\mu_0)\sim N(\mu-\mu_0,\Sigma)$. Then I used a quadratic form theorem that says

> Proposition: If $Y\sim N_p(\mu,\Sigma)$ with symmetric matrix $A$. Then $Y'AY\sim
>  \chi^2_{[r(A),\delta=\mu'A\mu]}$ (r is the rank) if and only if $A\Sigma$ is an
>   idempotent matrix.

Taking $A=\Sigma^{-1}\Rightarrow A\Sigma=I=I^2$ that is idempotent so
$$Q=Y'\Sigma^{-1}Y\sim \chi^2_{[r(A),\delta=\mu'A\mu]}$$
Under $H_0$ $\mu=\mu_0$ so
$$Q=\chi_{r(A)}^2=\chi_p^2$$
since $\Sigma_{p\times p}$, but under $H_1$ I don't understood why $\delta=n(\mu-\mu_0)'\Sigma^{-1}(\mu-\mu_0)$ and not just $\delta=(\mu-\mu_0)'\Sigma^{-1}(\mu-\mu_0)$?

About the $F$ distribution I know that $T$ have Hotteling distribution and it come directly from it, but is there a way to use the proposition above to reach the $F$ distribution?

Comment: Please add `[self-study]` tag.

Comment: When you next edit, put *Hotelling* for "*hotteling*"